# Uploading a File to Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I'm trying to use a simple upload method to put a simple image to one of our testing buckets. I can successfully send a GET query and access the bucket information but when I do a file change and select an image to upload to the bucket, the content length isn't being sent and the image is broken.

```
var zz = {
    path: "upload/storage/v1/b/" + this.bucket + "/o?uploadType=media&name=" + encodeURIComponent(vBody.name), 
    method: "POST",
    headers:  { 
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + tok, 
        "Content-Type": vFiles[k].type, 
        "Content-Length": vFiles[k].size 
    }, 
    body: vFiles[k] 
}
gapi.client.request(zz).then(res => { console.log(res); });
```

The file successfully posts, but the image is broken and displays a size of 2B or 0B when its more like 25 kb.

Edit:

I'm trying not to bring up node in this project and would like to avoid it if necessary.

Comment: i don't think there is enough information provided, the obvious solution would be that `vFiles[k].size` returns an incorrect value could you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: vFiles[k] is a files list array. This is an onchange of a file upload input.